# Use Rx native instead of Event

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, system.reactive

I want to convert event code using `e.cancel` to RX code.

```
public void CounsumerMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (x == 0) {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot effectively convert this code to proper Rx code, because this is not a Pure event - the caller of the event (i.e. the framework code) will *immediately* check the "Cancel" value, whereas Rx will not guarantee that it will set that variable in-context. You'll make an Observable that works sometimes and mysteriously fails in other scenarios.

Comment: So, is there something with a similar mechanic within the reactive paradigm? I see this query/response pattern pretty often in older code and more often than not, I just leave it the way it is because I don't know how to get similar behavior in a more functional way.

Comment: If you can ignore the Cancel part or somehow handle it immediately (i.e. Always Cancel), you can convert it to an Observable - you just can't try to pass the Cancel in the Observable

Comment: @PaulBetts can I use canceling an asynchronous operation ?